# Why ignore the horizontal size specified by the table?

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring, html-table

I'm working on a `Spring-Mvc` project.

I'm currently using a table to draw content, but there's a problem with the `horizontal size` being ignored.

Even though you have specified a size, why ignore the size you specified?

**table.jsp**

```
                                <table class="tb-regist" id="">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th style="width: 7%">type</th>
                                            <th style="width: 20%">new</th>
                                            <th style="width: 7%">check</th>
                                            <th style="width: 11%">title</th>
                                            <th style="width: 55%" colspan="2">body</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody id="tbody">
```

**CSS**

```css
table.tb-regist {
    width:100%;
    background-color:#fff;
}
```

[image]

I need your soluction. Thanks in advance

Comment: I made a fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/wntjsfb3/  Seems OK to me.   Worth mentioning that this is not a Spring issue, even though the html/css were generated from it.

Comment: Yes, I didn't know why the designated area was ignored, but I solved it with the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add "table-layout: fixed"

in css

```
table.tb-regist {
    width:100%;
    background-color:#fff;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
```

Comment: It's same and I can see warning `Undefined attribute name 
 (fixed).`

Comment: `Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - Undefined attribute name (table-
  layout:).
 - Undefined attribute name (table-
  layout:).`

Comment: sorry about that. it should be table-layout: fixed should be in css